# XSL doesn't transform field when condition on attributes are applied

Tags: xml, xslt

The following XSL doesn't work as desired. When the capacity (litre) value is anything other than "Other" it returns correct structure but when the value is "other" it doesn't include correct values. Let me know if any further detail is needed. Please note that field names are different when Capacity(litres) = Other.

```
    <M TStamp="2020-09-27T14:35:05">
           <F1 LCode="1" OwnerId="3275910">
              <F2 FId="118163"  />
              <RF3>
                 <Field Name="Capacity (litre)" Value="8,000" TStamp="2020-09-27T14:35:13">
                    <Child  Name="Serial Number" Value="123" TStamp="2020-09-27T14:35:17" />
                    <Child  Name="Barcode" Value="0001" TStamp="2020-09-27T14:35:39" />
                 </Field>
                 <Field  Name="Capacity (litre)" Value="Other" TStamp="2020-09-27T14:36:00">
                    <Child Name="Please Enter The Size" Value="9999" TStamp="2020-09-27T14:36:12" />
                    <Child Name="Other Serial Number" Value="456" TStamp="2020-09-27T14:36:18" />
                    <Child Name="Barcode" Value="0002" TStamp="2020-09-27T14:36:35" />
                 </Field>
              </RF3>
           </F1>
    </M>
```

What I want is :

```
<Detail>
    <SDetail>
        <BarCode>0001</Barcode>
        <SerialNumber>123</SerialNumber>
        <Capacity>8,000</Capacity>
    </SDetail>
    <SDetail>
        <BarCode>0002</BarCoder>
        <SerialNumber>456</SerialNumber>
        <Capacity>9999</Capacity>
    </SDetail>
</Detail>
```

The XSL I have is :

```
<xsl:template match="/M">


<Detail/>
<xsl:for-each select="F1/RF3/Field[@Name='Capacity (litre)']">

                            <xsl:variable name="cap">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                            </xsl:variable>     
                            
                            <xsl:choose>
                            
                            
                            <xsl:when test="$cap !='Other'">

                        <SDetail>
                            <BarCode>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Child[@Name='BarCode']/@Value"/>
                            </BarCode>

                            <SerialNumber>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Child[@Name='Serial Number']/@Value""/>
                            </SerialNumber>

                            <Capacity>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                            </Capacity>
                        </SDetail>
                        </xsl:when>


                            <xsl:when test="$cap ='Other'">

                        <SDetail>
                            <BarCode>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Child[@Name='BarCode']/@Value"/>
                            </BarCode>

                            <SerialNumber>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Child[@Name='Other Serial Number']/@Value""/>
                            </SerialNumber>

                                <Capacity>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Child[@Name='Please Enter The Size']/@Value"/>
                                </Capacity>
                            </SDetail>
                            </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each >


  
    
    </xsl:template>
```

I changed some of the names to post this question so if there is any typo please accept my apology.

The current output is

```
<Detail>
    <SDetail>
        <Barcode>0001</Barcode>
        <SerialNumber>123</SerialNumber>
        <Capacity>8,000</Capacity>
    </SDetail>
    <SDetail>
        <Barcode>0002</Barcode>
        <SerialNumber></SerialNumber>
        <Capacity>Other</Capacity>
    </SDetail>
</Detail>
```

Comment: I fixed a few typos in your code and I am getting the expected result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVruFNC

Comment: Note that your code could be shortened to: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVruFNC/1

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks for the great help :)